# How to programmatically set a customizable Option in magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-options

I'm creating an order via code, more or less along the lines of [How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2).

But I don't find a way to set a customizable option, that already exists on the product, by code. How to do it?

Comment: You want to set the custom options for order?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my on question, you can set the option on the `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item` item:

```
private function setOptionValue($product, $item, $optionTitle, $valueTitle)
{
    $option = $this->getOption($product, $optionTitle);
    $value = $this->getValue($option, $valueTitle);

    if (!$value) {
        throw new \Exception("Value \"$valueTitle\" could not be set for option \"{$option->getTitle()}\" for product {$product->getId()}");
    }

    $item->addOption(
        $this->option->create()
            ->setCode('option_'.$option->getId())
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setValue($value->getId())
    );

    $item->addOption(
        $this->option->create()
            ->setCode('option_ids')
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setValue($option->getId())
    );
}

private function getOption($product, $title)
{
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option->getTitle() == $title) {
            return $option;
        }
    }
}

private function getValue($option, $title)
{
    foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) {;
        if ($value->getTitle() == $title) {
            return $value;
        }
    }
}
```

The second add option block somehow does the trick. It add an entry to the quote_item_option table containing the code "option_ids" and the option IDs as value.

Can be done with arrays only also:

```
       $item->setOptions([
           ['product_id'=>299, 'code'=>'option_4', 'value'=>'10'],
          ['product_id'=>299, 'code'=>'option_ids', 'value'=>4]
       ]);
```