# how to create guest order in Magento-2 using test.php file

Tags: magento-2.1, orders

I try to create an order programmatically in magento2 using this code snippet found on webkul.com

Order I want to create for guest customer.while script executing customer creating ... I don't want that
Can any one help me to create orders for guest with out creating customers

Answer (score 0):

Following links will help you in creating guest order

https://blog.amasty.com/creating-magento-2-orders-programmatically/
http://webkul.com/blog/create-quote-and-order-programmatically-in-magento2/

Comment: Sorry Both are same they are creating customers if customers not exist. What i need is if customer not exist need to place order with guest mode only

Comment: Anyone found answer for this guest mode order creation programmatically?

Comment: Yes i found it i was created also order programatically

Comment: @pawankumar Share link

Answer (score 0):

Will give you clues how to create it:

First you need to create guest quote:

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;

$quoteId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart();
$quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quoteId);
```

Then add product:

```
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$addressData = [
         'telephone' => '', //fill data
         'email' => '', //fill data
         'firstname' => '', //fill data
         'lastname' => '', //fill data
         'street' => '', //fill data
         'city' => '', //fill data
         'country_id' => '', //add country code you need
         'postcode' => '', //fill data
          'save_in_address_book' => 0
         ];
$quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //Add any shipping method, should be enabled
$quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //Add any you want, payment method should be enabled
$quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
$quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']); //Add any you want, payment method should be enabled
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

And after there is quote with products, shipping method, payment method (that doesn't require any action after order is placed), you can place guest order:

```
use Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartManagementInterface;    
$orderId = $this->guestCartManagement->placeOrder($quoteId)
```

After order placed, you should bet order id in response.

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me. I would post the entire function but I have heavily modified it to do more custom things relevant to the module I am was working on that will just clutter up the answer

I followed the way done on here using the 3rd answer down which works on 2.1.

[How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2)

then changed this line

```
    $cart = $this->cartRepogitoryInterface->get($cart->getId());
```

to

```
        $cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId())->setCheckoutMethod(CartManagementInterface::METHOD_GUEST);
```

which can be found in this file 
magento-2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/GuestCart/GuestCartManagement.php

you will also need to add

use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;

And don't forget to remove the customer creation parts.