# How to place order automatically on selected date by customer in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1, extensions

I want to create one extension in that I want below functionality so please help me with that

-> customer can choose the date from my account section
-> On the selected date, customer-selected products placed in the order with COD.

Please suggest any extension or steps

thanks!

Comment: I believe that you are  you describing subscriptions?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not so descriptive. So from what I understand is you want to schedule orders.

You can create a module/Script for creating orders programmatically. You basically need to save all your order data that is needed to create an order and with the date you want to create a real order.

You can then place a cron and call your script which will check the dates every day and if the day matches the correct day it will create an order programmatically.

But there are problems due to less description what about payments. If there are offline payment methods then the above thing can be implemented else you need much more things to think and do.

Comment: I think his requirement is he wants to make Automatic order periodically every month. this is like a birthday notification @userpk

Comment: yes Exactly @userpk

Comment: can you provide any link for reference? @userpk

Comment: I dont have the reference for your requirement. You can start from how you can create orders programmatically. `https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2`