# Magento 2 Place orders directly from shopping cart page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have a Magento 2 website for Business to Agents. All agents (customers) need to be registered first in order to place an order.

I want to **skip** the **checkout page** as when an agent logged in on Frontend, system already know their billing address and delivery address. And orders will be paid by invoces, so no online payment needed.

Is that possbble to make a "Place order" button on **shopping cart** page (example.com/checkout/cart), so when customer click on it, an order will be placed without going through checkout page(example.com/checkout)?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.2 introduced Instant Purchase with the help of which login customer with default billing and shipping address set in address book can buy any product from product page. To achieve this functionality on cart page you can add a button on cart page and on click you can add ajax call for creating order.

You can read following link that discuss how you can create order in magento 2

[How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2)

By following above procedure you can achieve placing order on cart page.