# Possibility of creating order programatically without quote

Tags: magento2, orders, quote, programmatically

Has anyone checked wheter it is possible to add order programatically without creation of quote?

Comment: Check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2 hmm..  I just read without quote....

Answer (score 0):

to create an order, you need some items in your cart? A cart is a quote in Magento world.

Of course, you may want to directly feed the **sales_order**, **sales_order_item** tables with a custom feature. But you will lose a lot of feature by doing this?

- for instance, most cart abandonment features will not work with this feature
- not to mention it is likely your script will need to be fully bespoke and very much not compatible with future upgrade?

Having said this, I am very interested to hear more about your intentions and ideas where this would go as I imagine you may have thought through these pitfalls already. good luck

Comment: It is order migration form legacy system. I don't need cart data, performance is a key - so omitting cart operations would improve speed significantly. I was wondering if someone has done it before and if it has some consequnces I should take into account.

Comment: In this case create the orders using Magento and then clear the quotes. There is a setup for old quotes to be removed automatically