# Magento 2 set created date to order when creating

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, sales-order

I have followed the below steps to create an order in magento 2. But i want to set my preference date when creating it.

[How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can observe the event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` and set the `created_at` field in there.
This event is dispatched before the order is persisted in the db and you get as parameter the order object.
But this event gets dispatched for every order. So you have to mark your "manual" orders somehow.

So in the script that creates the quote you can do something like this before `$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);`:

```
$quote->setData('is_manual_order', true);
```

and your event observer can look like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class QuoteSubmitBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        if ($quote && $order && $quote->getData('is_manual_order')) {
            $order->setCreatedAt(your custom date here);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code.