# Magento 2 place order in custom controller (difference between placeOrder and submit)

Tags: magento2, programmatically, place-order

In [How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2) it shows two methods on how to place a quote as an order. The first method uses

```
$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
```

via `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement`. This returns an `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order` object.

The second method is using

```
$cart = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cart->getId());
$order_id = $this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId());
```

This method uses both the `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface` and the `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface`.

Another approach I found is basically the first one, but using `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface` instead...

What are the differences between those approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$this->cartManagementInterface->placeOrder($cart->getId())`  will still use `$this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);` to create the order, only difference is that after the order is successfully created, the checkout session is updated with the quote and order details:

```
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quote->getId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quote->getId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
    $this->checkoutSession->setLastOrderStatus($order->getStatus());
```

This is useful if you're placing your order from frontend since the success page is using the checkoutSession info for displaying.