# How to Place order programmatically Magento 2

Tags: magento2, place-order

ive built a custom payment method followed a few tutorials to get the output.
but im now stuck at the point where 'Place Order' won't work.

I am using Magento 2. If i could get some guidance on where to call my payment method to display the success page that would be great.

I currently have this setup in my model.

```
<?php

     namespace Jacks\Custompayment\Model;
    /**
    * Class Custompayment
    *
    * @method \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodExtensionInterface 
      getExtensionAttributes()
     *
     */
     class Custompayment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\cc
     {
     const PAYMENT_METHOD_CUSTOMPAYMENT_CODE = 'custompayment';
    /**
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = self::PAYMENT_METHOD_CUSTOMPAYMENT_CODE;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_formBlockType = \Emipro\Custompayment\Block\Form\Custompayment::class;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_infoBlockType = \Emipro\Custompayment\Block\Info\Custompayment::class;


    protected $_canAuthorize= true;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPayableTo()
    {
        return $this->getConfigData('payable_to');
    }
     /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->getConfigData('businessID');
    }
     /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->getConfigData('password');
    }

     public function authorize(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        if (!$this->canAuthorize()) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('The authorize action is not available.'));
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder($cartId,\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null) 
    {

    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try 
    {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    }
     catch (\Exception $e) 
     {

        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

Comment: Why you use the deprecated method instead of payment gateway?

Comment: i read now that its deprecated. i want the order to process within magento and not get redirected out. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are some links you can refer

**https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html**

**[How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2)**

Comment: Thank you very much, il try them out @Mohit Rane

Comment: have you solved your problem ?

Comment: no sorry, it still doesnt place the order and redirect me the success page @Mohit Rane

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
class OrderCreator
{
private $objectManager;

public function __construct()
{
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $this->objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
}

public function createOrderFromQuote($existingQuoteId, $customerId)
{
    $existingQuote = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository::class)->get($existingQuoteId);

    $newQuote = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory::class)->create();
    $newQuote->setStoreId(1);
    $newQuote->assignCustomer($this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class)->getById($customerId));
    $newQuote->setIsActive(true);

    foreach ($existingQuote->getItems() as $item) {
        $product = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::class)->get($item->getSku());
        $quoteItem = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item::class);
        $quoteItem->setProduct($product);
        $quoteItem->setQuote($newQuote);
        $quoteItem->setQty($item->getQty());
        $newQuote->addItem($quoteItem);
    }

    $shippingAddress = $newQuote->getShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');

    $newQuote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
    $newQuote->collectTotals();
    $newQuote->getPayment()->setMethod("checkmo");
    $newQuote->save();

    $cartManagement = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface::class);
    $orderInterface = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class);
    
    try {
        $orderId = $cartManagement->placeOrder($newQuote->getId());
        $order = $orderInterface->load($orderId);
        $incrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
        echo "Increment ID: " . $incrementId . "\n";
        echo "Order ID: " . $orderId . "\n";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error placing order: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

}