# Magento 2.3: Order Create Programatically Script Allowed memory exhausted

Tags: orders, programmatically, magento2.3.0, memory-leak

I am working on creating orders dynamically using custom magento script , got reference from [How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2)

now when I run script, after making 10-15 orders, first script goes slow and later on , it shows below error

`Allowed memory exhausted`

I tried to make script in a manner so that I can release the assigned variable as soon as they finish there task, even still I am unable to understand, what exactly allocating that much memory , that it exhausted.

I can't extend `memory_limit` , so please do not suggest me to do so.
I have to run script in a limited given memory instance.

please help anybody.

thanks in advance