# Order Sync in Netsuite Magento 2.4.2-p1 EE

Tags: sales-order, magento2.4.2-p1, netsuite

I want sync new created order in Netsuite ERP system.

I followed this [Link](https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#Add-a-Record-with-a-Custom-Field) but i am facing Error

> **Error :-**
>
> You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to add to Magento orders created in Netsuite or any other system?
If yes, you can create a webapi in Magento, and you can hit this endpoint from your system with the required information in the payload. You can check [How to create order programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116435/how-to-create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2).

If you want to send to Netsuite orders from Magento, then you could add an observer, for example for `sales_order_place_after` and get the order information from it, and send the parsed information to Netsuite endpoint for further processing in there.

Comment: i want to code similar like this https://github.com/netsuitephp/netsuite-php/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#Add-a-Record-with-a-Custom-Field

Comment: 1+ for Response :)